# Convert bgr to ycbcr and separate channels in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I need convert my capturing frame (Mat) convert to YCBCR and separate the channels, How I can do?

My code:

```
frame_capturado = cvQueryFrame( capture );
cvtColor(frame_capturado,frameycbcr,CV_BGR2YCrCb);
```

And now...?

In concret i need cr channel

Comment: The title says convert BGR to YCbCr but the code proposed converts to YCrCb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and now ...

```
Mat ycrcb[3];
split(frameycbcr, ycrcb);

// do work

Mat ycrcb_merged;
merge(ycrcb,3, ycrcb_merged);
```

(and please use VideoCapture instead of CvCapture, don't mix old c-api and newer c++ api.)

Comment: thanks, and with mixchannels function it is possible? maybe:        int ch[]={2,0};
cr.create(frameycbcr.size(), frameycbcr.depth());
mixChannels(&frameycbcr,1,&cr,1,ch,1);

Comment: yes, mixchannels will work as well. but note that the 1st arg is an array of channels, not the frameycbcr image.